# GET /wpad.dat entries flooding my access_log

Tags: log-files, flooding, wpad.dat, wpad

I have a small LAN of some 30 users in it with proxy auto configuration enabled and working.

Two of them are requesting wpad.dat file too rapidly at a pace of 30 times per second.

```
10.1.14.246 - - [02/Jun/2014:09:07:18 +0200] "GET /wpad.dat HTTP/1.1" 302 302
10.1.14.141 - - [02/Jun/2014:09:07:18 +0200] "GET /wpad.dat HTTP/1.1" 302 302
```

I don't know whether this is a problem from performance perspective, (the server is powerful enough to handle this) but the problem is it clogs up the access_log file.
It grows about 1GB per week.

Clients run Win7Pro. What could cause this behavior? What can be done to stop it?
I have shortened log rotate window as a temporary workaround to prevent /var fill up.

Thanks beforehand for your support.

Comment: Have you looked at the config on those systems and confirmed it's the same as a known good system ?

Comment: @lain: What could be configured differently? It's just a "tick" at "Use proxy auto configuration" in Firefox and IE.